# Why does a Super Class Object initialized with a sub class constructor inherit the subclass methods but not its variables

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have difficulty in understanding the concept of inheritance in the following code.

```
package testPackage;

public class Threaddy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MainThread mt = new SubThread();
        mt.run(); //Output -> This is SubThread
        System.out.println(mt.i); //Output -> 2
    }
}

class MainThread {
    int i = 2;
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("This is Main Thread");
    }
}

class SubThread extends MainThread {
    int i = 1;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("This is Subthread");
    }

}
```

Here i have 2 classes MainThread(Super-class) and SubThread(Sub-class).

I have created an object of the Super Class as `mt` but initialized with the new constructor of the subclass. I believe this is possible as the subclass extends the super-class.

However when i execute the method of this super-class object, it runs the sub-class instance of the method `run`. But if i try to print out the variable `i` it returns only the super-class verison of `int i` .

My Question is why does it run the Sub-class method, but has only the super-class version of the variable?

Is there any way(without changing the way i initialize the objects) to access the super-class method `run()` and access the sub-class version of the variable `i` ?

Comment: Fields aren't overridden; only methods are.

Comment: As an object-oriented programming concept, we have method overriding ability. This concept is not true about fields and variables.

Comment: To access the sub-class version of the variable `((SubThread) mt).i`. All instance methods are in C# terms virtual, meaning if a child overrides its parent's method, the child's implemenatation will be called.

Comment: To access the super-class method `run`: Your subclass would have to expose its parent's method by having a method in the following fashion `void superRun() { super.run(); }`. Then you'd call it by `((SubThread) mt).superRun();`